I get java.awt.HeadlessException: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set. on Ubuntu server
Hi im running a server with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS , i'm running several minecraft servers on it and now when i try to install a new one i get this error,
java -jar forge-1.20.1-47.2.20-installer.jar

Host: authserver.mojang.com [Unknown]
Data kindly mirrored by CreeperHost at https://www.creeperhost.net/
java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set,
or no headful library support was found,
but this program performed an operation which requires it,
at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:166)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:501)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.(Window.java:453)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.(Window.java:608)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.(Dialog.java:674)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.(Dialog.java:519)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JDialog.(JDialog.java:426)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JOptionPane.createDialog(JOptionPane.java:957)
at net.minecraftforge.installer.InstallerPanel.run(InstallerPanel.java:279)
at net.minecraftforge.installer.SimpleInstaller.launchGui(SimpleInstaller.java:182)
at net.minecraftforge.installer.SimpleInstaller.main(SimpleInstaller.java:154)
Exception in thread "main"
java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set,
or no headful library support was found,
but this program performed an operation which requires it,
at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:166)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.(Window.java:553)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:428)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:393)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame.(SwingUtilities.java:1925)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame(SwingUtilities.java:2001)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JOptionPane.getRootFrame(JOptionPane.java:1696)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(JOptionPane.java:875)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:677)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:648)
at net.minecraftforge.installer.SimpleInstaller.launchGui(SimpleInstaller.java:185)
at net.minecraftforge.installer.SimpleInstaller.main(SimpleInstaller.java:154)

i'm at a loss as to what to do, i've uninstalled and purged java then reinstalled. Still doesnt work. Does anyone know anything about this ? I'm not runninng x11 , but it was installed earlier and then uninstalled and purged.
Any help or hints appreciated

The error clearly says it is expecting an X11 DISPLAY variable. I just cut and pasted that from your question.

Yes was thinking that this was the problem, how would one go about to remedy this ? im not even sure where to look.
